# Why I cant get values of the checkboxes in this html table using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, html-table

I have a table where I have some checkboxes but when I select them and click submit it doesn't do anything. The strangest thing is that if I place the  tags inside  as they suppose to be it doesn't work, I cant submit any values:

```
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all"></th>
                <th>Dev.no</th>
                <th>IMEI</th>
                <th>Serial no.</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
                <th>Device</th>
                <th>Date added on stock</th>
                <th>Report comment</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
```

BUT , if I place the  tags outside then it works, I am able to get the values HOWEVER table loses pagination:

```
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all"></th>
                <th>Dev.no</th>
                <th>IMEI</th>
                <th>Serial no.</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
                <th>Device</th>
                <th>Date added on stock</th>
                <th>Report comment</th>
            </thead>
        </tr>
```

**Any idea why this weird behavior is happening? What am I doing wrong here?**

UPDATE: jQuery code below

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            'columnDefs': [{
                'targets': 0,
                'searchable': true,
                'orderable': true,
                'className': 'dt-body-center'

            }]
        });
    });      

    $('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e) {
        var form = this;
        table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            if (!$.contains(document, this)) {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $(form).append(
                        $('<input>')
                        .attr('type', 'hidden')
                        .attr('name', this.name)
                        .val(this.value)
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show your jquery code?

Comment: @HadiPawar check the updated post!

Comment: @HadiPawar did you check it?

Comment: @HadiPawar please help!

Comment: let me see it now

Comment: In datatable u initialized table  #example and in submit trigger '#frm-example'...i think both are same table..then use same table id for both and which should be present in html ..

Comment: fixed it, I had to wrap the entire table with form

Comment: Your table isn't set up correctly, at least from what is listed. Where is the `<table>` declaration?